# Encoding with PostgreSQL ODBC driver (32-bit)

Tags: windows, postgresql, encoding, odbc, excel-2013

I'm facing a character encoding problem using the ODBC driver.
I'm trying to retrieve some data from an in-house PostgreSQL server with Excel 2013,
but the Japanese characters gets garbled or replaced with an empty string.

Here are what I use:

- [Client] Windows 7 Enterprise 32-bit & Excel 2013 32-bit
- [ODBC driver] psqlodbc_09_05_0400-x86
- [Server] PostgreSQL 8.2.3 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.6

Encoding settings on the server:

- server_encoding=SQL_ASCII
- client_encoding=SJIS

Notes:

- Neither of the driver ("PostgreSQL Unicode" nor "PostgreSQL ANSI") worked.
- I've set the below strings separately to "ConnSettings" option (in the connection strings) with no avail:
  - SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'SJIS'
  - SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'EUC_JP'
  - SET CLIENT_ENCODING = 'SJIS'
  - SET CLIENT_ENCODING = 'EUC_JP'
- I've tried the "pgAdmin" app but couldn't get rid of garbled characters.

How can I avoid character garbling?
Any comment would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the server encoding of `SQL_ASCII`.

With this server encoding, PostgreSQL isn't encoding aware and will not perform character conversion, so your client receives the data just as they are in the database. If that is not correct, you are out of luck.

The correct solution is to use a different server encoding like `EUC_JP` or (better) `UTF8`.

The client encoding should probably be `SJIS`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @LaurenzAlbe.  I had my problem solved with the following workaround:  One of my senior colleagues had an installer for an older version of the ODBC driver (I could not identify the exact version, but its last-updated date was year 2005, so maybe around version 08).  After the installation, I was able to select "PostgreSQL" (without the suffix like ANSI/Unicode) in the ODBC Data Source Administrator.  In addition to the use of that, I chose "Microsoft Query" instead of "Data Connection Wizard" in Excel.  This was the only way to get rid of character garbling.

Comment: Then you are lucky that the encodings happen to match.